# Influence on performance of using 'private static final' strings in Spring 3 REST controller

Tags: performance, rest, spring-mvc

I'm working on REST API based on Spring 3 MVC. In each call I'm adding to JSON response two variables: 'description' and 'result'.
For example:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "entity.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView get() {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView(JSON_VIEW);
    mav.addObject("description", "entity list");
    mav.addObject("result", someService.getAll());
    return mav;
}
```

Does it make sense for performance of the app to create a pool of `private static final` strings and use them every time I need?
I mean like this:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

    private static final String JSON_VIEW = "jsonView";

    private static final String VAR_DESCRIPTION = "description";
    private static final String VAR_RESULT = "result";

    private static final String DESC_CREATED = "entity created";
    private static final String DESC_ENTITY_LIST = "entity list";
    private static final String DESC_ACCESS_DENIED = "forbidden";

    @RequestMapping(value = "entity.htm", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public ModelAndView put(HttpServletResponse response) {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView(JSON_VIEW);
        if (!entityService.someChecking()) {
            mav.addObject(VAR_DESCRIPTION, DESC_ACCESS_DENIED);
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN);
        } else {
            mav.addObject(VAR_DESCRIPTION, DESC_CREATED);
            mav.addObject(VAR_RESULT, entityService.save(new Entity()));
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_CREATED);
        }
        return mav;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "entity.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView get(HttpServletResponse response) {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView(JSON_VIEW);
        if (!entityService.someChecking()) {
            mav.addObject(VAR_DESCRIPTION, DESC_ACCESS_DENIED);
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN);
        } else {
            mav.addObject(VAR_DESCRIPTION, DESC_ENTITY_LIST);
            mav.addObject(VAR_RESULT, entityService.getAll());
        }
        return mav;
    }

    // and so on
}
```

Someone of these statuses I use only once, but DESC_ACCESS_DENIED I use up to 10 times in one REST controller.

Answer (score 0):

Your get is not returning json, it returns a view.

I prefer using an enum instead of static final ints - easier to add functionality later.

Comment: Yes it can. See the OP's comment on the other answer. Moreover you can send `JSON` even with a jsp using `<%@ page contentType="application/json" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>`.

Comment: @zeroflagL the code in question states that the method returns a modelandview. Json is json, there is no presentation logic in json. The other coment doesn't make sense, its defining a bean called jsonView of the type jacksonmapper, a jacksonmapper simply converts a pojo to json.

Comment: The client gets a `JSON` response. That's the only thing that matters.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does make sense. It's a good pratice. It save's you time and effort if you ever need to change this values. It's quite insignificant in terms of memory use or process time, but it's better.

If you intend to use those strings more than once, then it is a good pratice to turn then into static final. But notice your methods aren't returning JSON responses. A JSON response is something like that:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/porUF", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody List<Municipio> municipios(
            @RequestParam(value = "uf", required = true) String uf) {

        if ( uf.length() != 2) {
            return null;    
        }

        return municipioBO.findByUf(uf);
    }
```

The @ResponseBody annotation will transform the List into a JSON object, and the response of a HTTP GET for that is something like that:

```
[{"codigo":9701,"uf":{"uf":"DF","nome":"DISTRITO FEDERAL"},"nome":"BRASILIA                                     "}]
```

This is a JSON response.

Comment: I'm using one of spring's view:
<bean name="jsonView" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView"/>

Comment: "Yes" - Why? Some explanation would be fine.